# ActiveMQ web console as a Restful API?

Tags: rest, activemq-classic, admin

Is there a Restful API built-in or as a plugin I can use to achieve the same actions I can do with the admin web console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the management operations from the web admin console are available via a [REST management interface (scroll down to the "Rest Management" section)](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html) which exposes all the underlying JMX MBeans via Jolokia.

Comment: Ok - made it to work, So when I get a list, the answer includes the link on how I fetch data for specific queue or topic and I guess I can follow that way to find more data, but, is there a way to see all the possible endpoints?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "endpoints"? Are you talking about queues and topics? If so, I think you could probably use the `getQueues` and `getTopics` methods on the `BrokerViewMBean`.

Comment: My environemnt is PHP. My system monitoring and admin panel is written in PHP, so I need to use REST API calls to AMQ to manage it, not call directly Java objects. 
By end points I mean, how would the request (if there is one) to look at the queued messages look like, for example, and what else is exposed via the REST API (Jolokia), Although, if I understand what you write, it mean Julukia wraps anything that can be done with the Java API, right?

Comment: My env is PHP, so the Java world is kind of foreign to me. That said, I see now what an mbean is. And how to use it. So what I actually mean by end points, is is there a place I can what MBeans are exposed via Jolokia and what are the methods?

Comment: Checkout the [Jolokia documentation](https://jolokia.org/reference/html/protocol.html). Scroll down to the `Searching MBeans` section. You should be able to search for MBeans starting with `org.apache.activemq`.